# Interchangable compatablity of circuit breaker brands

Tags: electrical-panel

I have an older General Electric panel that I need to install a 30-amp tandem circuit breaker to create

2 240 volt circuits.  The GE panel accepts TQL-AC, TQAL-AC, THQL-AC, THQA, TXQL, type breakers.  What brands are interchangable that would fit the GE panel.

Comment: Why are you looking for an alternative?  All those GE breakers you listed are widely available at reasonable prices.

Comment: If you're hoping to use half-width tandem breakers to get a 240V circuit in a 1" slot, it looks like you're probably out of luck -- GE's tandem breakers are called THQP, which your panel does not list, and GE uses a different connection mechanism for these than any other manufacturer, so there are no substitutes available.

Comment: Can we have a photo of the panel and the panel labeling?  You can [edit] this into your question.

Comment: Yes, can we have photos of your panel, including clear shots of the labeling on the inside of the door please?

Answer (score 5):

Short version: you can't cross breaker brands.   You cannot put a competitor breaker type in this panel.

A "tandem" breaker is not what you want.  [Here is an article about those.](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/110151/what-is-a-tandem-breaker-aka-duplex-cheater-twin-double-stuff-etc)

What you're hoping to use is a THQP or TQP breaker, which *appears* very similar to a tandem breaker, however, is actually a 2-pole breaker that is half-height.  On certain GE panels, GE has a system that uses 1/2" tall (half-height) breakers, 2 per breaker space.  Their 2-pole breakers in that system are 1" tall and straddle 2 breaker spaces, with a 1/2" breaker above and below them.

You can't use them.  Those half-width breakers clip onto a special "cruciform" cross-bars added to the bus stabs, and *your bus stabs don't have them*.    You can see the cross-bars in the lower 5 rows of this panel here:

[image]

Comment: The "H" in a GE breaker part number just means HACR.  So with and without the H is ok.

Comment: @Bryce interesting, I've never seen them on shelves without the "H".  And for the record I just did an edit to add the word "cruciform" so I have a chance of ever finding this photo again. It's very helpful when explaining GE thins.